# hashCode and Aggregation

Tags: java, language-agnostic

Is there a standard meta-algorithm or best practice of how to implement the hashCode() method for classes that are composed of other classes:

```
class A { B b; C c;  ... }
```

If we assume that B and C put some effort in implementing their hashCode(), it is certainly a good idea to base `A`s hashcode on that of `B` and `C`. But how to best combine them?

I ask this because certain operations are obviously not well suited like in:

```
class Naive {
   B b1, b2;
   public int hashCode() { return b1.hashCode() ^ b2.hashCode(); }
}
```

This would cause a hash code of 0 for every Naive object that happens to have two equal `B` objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nwinkler's algorithm (which is in fact what would be generated by Eclipse when using the Source > Generate hashcode and equals... functionality) is similar to what Joshua Bloch describes in Effective Java (as referenced in Puce's answer).

The idea is to combine hashcodes computed for significant fields. The use of the odd prime number 31 can result in a jvm optimization of the multiplication (into a shift + substraction). Note that you **must** exclude fields that are not used in equals() from this hashcode computation. You *may* exclude fields whose values are computed from fields included in the computation.

The suggested hashcode computation for an Object field is simply to recursively call its hashcode method, provided it is not null (in which case we use 0) and the object's equals() method is itself recursively called in our equals() method. If the latter is not the case (equals does a more complex comparison on our object field), suggested approach is to construct a canonical representation and compute an hashcode for it.

To compute an hashcode for primitive fields, following methods are suggested (note that they must still be combined into the result by doing result = result * prime + fieldHashCode):

- float: `Float.floatToIntBits(f)`
- int, byte, char, short: `(int) f`
- long => `(int) (f ^ (f>>>32))`
- boolean: `(f?1:0)`
- double: `longHash= Double.doubleToLongBits(f)` then use `(int) (longHash^(longHash>>>32))`
- arrays: in java 1.5, some hashCode methods where introduced in the Arrays class. you can also apply previous rules recursively on the elements of the array as if they were fields themselves.

Answer (score 5):

This is a common pattern, which some Eclipse plug-ins are able to generate:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((b1 == null) ? 0 : b1.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((b2 == null) ? 0 : b2.hashCode());
    // repeat for other attributes you want to include...

    return result;
}
```

Don't forget to code the `equals()` method accordingly...

Answer (score 2):

Item 8 of the "Effective Java" book by Joshua Bloch shows a good algorithm:

http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf

If you use Java SE 7 you can also use:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash%28java.lang.Object...%29

Comment: Rather than just posting a link to an entire chapter of a book, perhaps you could post the algorithm itself?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time for that. I think giving the right direction is enough and I don't have to copy other sources.

Comment: @Puce - it is okay, I love to read PDFs. Just did not really know where to start for this specific subject. Hence you answer is indeed helpful.